# What are the problems that can arise if a network host has the subnet mask configured improperly?

Tags: router, ipv4, subnet, ip

Supposing the IP address is correct and the gateway IP address is also correct, but the mask is different than the one in the router/default gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A host masks its own IP address and the destination IP address. If the results are equal, the destination is on the same network, and the host will look for the destination MAC address in its ARP cache, send an ARP request if it is not found, then send the resulting frame via layer-2. If the network is not the same, the host will send the frame to its configured gateway.

If the host mask is larger than the network mask, the host will not be able to communicate with all the IP addresses in the network since it will send packets for those addresses outside the mask to the gateway, which will ignore them because they are on the same network as the gateway sees it.

If the host mask is smaller than the network mask, the host will not be able to communicate with hosts in any other networks encompassed by the mask since it will never send the packets to the gateway as it must to reach those networks.

Comment: The first problem might be mitigated by setting home routers to send the packets that are addressed to the same subnet to the MAC of the host (I guess that gateways also have MACs of the IP adresses int the subnet) even if the same subnet from which they came from. Is this commonly done or not? If it is not done I guess it would be for security reasons.

Comment: Regarding the second situation, after sending an ARP request and receiving no response wouldn't it be common behavior to send the packet to the gateway ?

Comment: Questions about home networking and/or consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. Those types of questions can be asked on [su].

Comment: In the second case, the frame will never be sent since there will no reply to the ARP request.